# Database Design

Tags: database-design

1. First question

> I have following entities: **Form** which can have some **Parameters**(but not necessarily), Form has **Tables**. In one case(if Form has no Parameters) i know advance what Tables correspond to the Form, in other case (if Form have Parameters that the user chooses) I decide which Tables to load depending on choosen Parameters.
>  How i can store this information in database? 
>   *[Update]* At this moment i have following schema: table Form, table FormParam, table Table; Form has relation to FormParam(one-to-many), Form has relation to Table(one-to-many); but in this schema doesn`t exist information about the dependence of Table from FormParam. I can do relation from FormParam to Table, but in my case not all situations Table depends from FormParam.

1. Second question

> I have one table which contains some data (catalog of organizations). In another table i have data which will  be selected by user from Form. In some Forms user must choose organization from list of organization. I want uniformity of data storage that a user selects from a Form, so i can duplicate records from the first table in the second, but i don`t want( i think this is bad style).
>  How should I to do in this case? 
>   *[Update]* Perhaps there is a solution in such a way to design a DataBase that I can specify a first table to refer to records stored in another table. Maybe I'm wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: It is quite unclear what you actually want to achieve. Please rewrite the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to spend some time designing your system's data model. Maybe your approaching would be changed from the "operating" to "data" itself.

To solve your problem now, you can create tables in N x N relation, where in table A you have the Form information and table B you have parameter information. In the 3rd table, NxN relation, you specify the properties that should load the desired tables (that would be stored in a string field in this table).

Be care about the complexity of your params. If you have many differend combinations, maybe you have too many records and to implement the table loading would be almost impossible.

Comment: thanks for the tips. How to be if the **Table** does not depend on the **Parameters**?  I have to split the logic for extracting **Tables** depending on the **Parameters** and **Tables** do not depend on the **Parameters**?

Comment: You should give more information about your system, that seems to be quite confusing for another person. But, according to my understandig, you ought to create a table more or less in this way:

Comment: (prm_parameter:int PK FK; prm_table:string). In the first field (prm_parameter) you must to somehow link with the form parameters filled by the user. In the second field, add the name of the table that you must to load when that parameter is selected/filled. Then, you'll able to load only the selected tables, when you query the table grouping by the field prm_table. It can solve the problem.